# XML Serialization - Convert object into XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization, null

I am serializing an object into XML.

consider class

```
public class EmpInfo
{
    public string Code;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Designation;
    public int Salary;
}
```

If I don't provide salary then it is by default set as 0
I don't want default values to be set.

In case of Designation, if I don't provide then value is automatically NULL.
That tag is not included in XML.

How should I omit the Salary tag if Salary is not provided?

Comment: Try nullable int. `public int? Salary;`

Comment: One way would be to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). Another method might be to have the `int Salary` be ignored in the XML _always_ and have a `string SalarySerialized` wrapper which does conversion. If the value is `0` it returns `null`, any other number it returns the string representation. EDIT: Oh fine l4V, give a better suggestion why don't you!

Comment: Regarding the nullable case, it seems that it will still include the tag when `null`; it outputs an element "<Salary xsi:nil="true" />"

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int/246359#246359

Comment: See example [this][1], is basic example or [this][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146804/xml-serialization-c-sharp
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722126/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization